# Razor syntax PHP equivalent

Tags: c#, php, asp.net, syntax, razor

Is there an equivalent to the new ASP.NET razor syntax in PHP?

Answer (score 7):

Thanks @mindplay.dk for linking to the Razor View Renderer for the Yii Framework!  I wanted to share a recent find, [Twig](http://www.twig-project.org/) (http://www.twig-project.org/) as an alternative if you are looking for a standalone template engine for PHP.  It's not Razor syntax, but it is *simple* and *extensible*.

Here's some examples from the site:

**For Each**:

```
{% for user in users %}
  * {{ user.name }}
{% else %}
  No user has been found.
{% endfor %}
```

**Blocks & Inheritance**:

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}

{% block content %}
  Content of the page...
{% endblock %}
```

**Filters**:

```
{{ "now"|date("m/d/Y") }}

{{ "I like %s and %s."|format(foo, "bar") }}
returns: I like foo and bar. (if the foo parameter equals to the foo string)
```

I'm still doing some preliminary development & testing with this engine and I'm liking it thus far!

Answer (score 5):

There is a Razor-like view-engine for the Yii framework:

http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/razorviewrenderer

It's very simple - it doesn't seem to have any real Yii dependencies, so I can't imagine it would be very difficult to pull this out of Yii and use it in a different context.

Mind you, this is just a Razor-style template parser - it compiles Razor-style templates into plain vanilla PHP scripts. It relies on Yii for the actual view-engine.

Comment: @what bout smarty?

Answer (score 5):

Laravel's Blade Template Engine, uses a similar syntax to Razor. https://laravel.com/docs/master/blade

Comment: I think even the name Blade is a not-so-subtle reference to Razor.

Answer (score 2):

The closest you'll find is inside [Fat-Free Framework](http://fatfree.sf.net)'s template engine, but it requires you to use curly braces. Instead of PHP's verbose `<?php echo $x['y']['z']; ?>` or the short tag-equivalent `<?=$x['y']['z']?>`, Fat-Free uses `{@x.y.z}`

Answer (score 1):

The only Razor-like syntax that PHP has something similar to is what I believe is called "variable expansion":

```
$two = "Two";
echo "One $two Three";
```

**Result:**

`One Two Three`

But, you can't use this outside of a PHP block or outside of a double-string for that matter (at least not for how you want to use it). This doesn't work:

```
<?php
$two = "Two";
?>
<p>One $two Three</p>
```

**Result:**

```
<p>One $two Three</p>
```

Other PHP programing constructs outside of PHP blocks do nothing as well. So, none of this stuff is paralleled in PHP: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/02/introducing-razor.aspx

Comment: Your first example is missing a `;` after the string assignment.

Comment: @Russell Dias - Thank you, I didn't spot that!

Comment: My php is rusty, but can't you use <?=$two?>

Comment: @pqsk: That is correct - I guess I should add a note about that too. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I just had to look "Razor syntax" up and it seems nice enough for ASP.NET. In PHP though I would apply some sort of template framework (I usually use [Smarty](http://www.smarty.net/) myself) to get some nice clean looking HTML-pages with only a minimum of control structure and variable referencing.

Comment: whenever somebody says "Smarty", I have to post two links: one to the fat-free alternative, [Dwoo](http://dwoo.org/) - and one to my own ultra-thin engine, [Outline](http://outline.mindplay.dk/) ... I'm not just shamelessly plugging my own engine here - Smarty is a dinosaur, and there are much better alternatives to templating with PHP...

Answer (score 1):

I'm actually working on a project that does exactly that! Just with a `$` instead of a `@`.

It's called [Phazor](https://www.npmjs.com/package/phazor) for Node.

Just install it `npm i phazor -g`

```
<head>
    /* Phazor comments inside html */
    ${
        // Vanilla PHP inside ${ }
        $title = "I love fruit";
        $isFruit = true;
    }

    /* An echo expression */
    <title>$(ucwords($title))</title>
</head>
<body>

    /* Variable expression */
    <h1>$title.</h1>

    /* Inline statement */
    $if ($isFruit) {
        <p>It sure is great!</p>
    }
</body>
```

Then run `phazor sourceFolder destinationFolder` and it will compile all the phazor **.ph** files into the destination folder. (It can also compile TypeScript and SASS files inside the folder)

Keep in mind this is not fully tested in a production environment.

Answer (score 0):

It seems someone did it: https://github.com/steffans/razr

But I would still convert to Twig, it is much more powerful.